# Is there a way to programmatically add new links to the primary links?

Tags: navigation

Is there a way to add links to the primary links using PHP in Drupal 6? The reason I ask is that I want to add more links in the footer of the web page, which I don't want to put in the top navigation level.

Answer (score 3):

You can either specifiy the menu name in [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) (look for 'menu_name') if they are defined with that hook or you can use [menu_link_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7).

Yet another option would be to use http://drupal.org/project/features and export your menu structure as a feature.

Comment: Any concrete example ? (i'm just starting drupal)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of how to do it, but I know you may use `hook_menu_link_alter()` or override the primary links function `theme_links()` in template.php.